# iPad, 3.2.1 update causes app to display black screen

Tags: opengl-es, ipad

I recently accidentally updated my iPad to version 3.2.1 and had to update Xcode and SDK to continue development.

However all of my apps that ran perfectly fine before, don't display anything when ran in the new versions.

There are no error messages and the apps seem to be running just fine, except that all that is displayed is a black screen.

Does anybody else know why? or is having the same experience?

All my apps use OpenGL ES for most of their drawing, if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer and ill add here in case anybody has the same problem.

Basically all of my MainWindow.xib files were set to not visible originally.

And for some reason they were displaying before but not in the new versions.
So I added the check mark to "initially visible" in the window options for that file and it worked.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on the iPhone. Install an adhoc or debug build by dragging into iTunes or via Xcode organizer = blank screen. Install via Xcode debugger - works fine